# in gtest, how to add lib file to executable test file

Tags: c++, c, cmake, googletest

I always get `undefined reference to m()`, here is my code:

ex.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

void m() {

}
```

ex.h

```
void m();
```

ex_test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "ex.h"

TEST(m, 1) {
    m();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(try)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(src ex.c)
add_executable(try ${src})
add_subdirectory(gtest)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR} ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_executable(ex_test ex_test.cpp ex.c)
target_link_libraries(ex_test gtest gtest_main)
```

here is my [output](https://gist.github.com/roroco/52dbc39b62b8ee96e32e) in clion(sorry, sof raise "mostly code" error when i copy it

Comment: What symbol are you getting the `undefined reference` for? It would be good if you could add the verbatim linkage errors.

Comment: @AntonioPérez it's "m()", I have update it

Comment: The symbol `m()` seems to be only referenced in `ex_test.cpp` and is defined in `ex.c` and both are part of the sources list for executable `ex_test` so it makes no sense that the linker cannot resolve the reference. Please, copy and paste the linker output messages as part of the question. For sure there is relevant information there to answer your question.

Comment: @AntonioPérez what do you mean "linker output", I just learn c.

Comment: The full output you get in console after calling `make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ex.c` is compiled as C. `ex_test.cpp` is compiled as C++ but refers to
`m()` from `ex.c`, so in `ex_test.cpp` you need to inform the compiler
that the declarations in `ex.h` have C linkage (hence no name-mangling).

Replace:

```
#include "ex.h"
```

with:

```
extern "C" {
#include "ex.h"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question title just have pointed what is the problem: you should add library of `ex` to the library files needed by  `ex_test`.

Compile `ex.c`, then append the compile result file `ex.a` to the library files needed by  `ex_test`. You can do that by `write CMakeLists.txt` file like below:

```
add_library(ex ex.c)
target_link_libraries(ex_test ex gtest gtest_main)
```

Comment: That's not the problem, he includes `ex.c` to the list of sources for `ex_test` executable.